# Django For loop template for dict data

Tags: python, django, dictionary

So in Python if i have a Dictionary rather than a list with a dataset, I would normally call (for example):

```
for i in myDictionary: 
 myDictionary[i]['event']
 myDictionary[i]['timestamp']
```

etc.

But in Django this does not work:

```
{% for i in myDictionary %} 
<tr> 
<td> {{ myDictionary.i.event }}</td>
<td> {{ myDictionary.i.timestamp }}</td>
</tr>
```

Does not produce results - what's the optimal way to handle dictionaries with an arbitrary number of keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a weird structure. What you want is a list of dictionaries.

```
myDicts = []
for i in myDictionary: 
    data = {'event': '...', 'timestamp': '...'}
    myDicts.append(data)
```

Then, you can loop over dictionary values by using [the function `.items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), like in a normal loop (but don't include the parenthesis):

```
{% for elem in myDicts %}
    {% for key, value in elem.items %} 
    <tr> 
       <td> {{ myDictionary.key }}</td>
       <td> {{ myDictionary.value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm sure that was somewhere in the templates documentation that I didn't commit to memory -_-   Thanks for the quick response